# Change form doest trigger when I change NgModel

Tags: angular, forms, angular-ngmodel

I have a form and i change the value of the input order, but the event (change) does not work.

The value is setted in the input correctly, but the change does not trigger.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="searchAdds(formAside)" (change)="searchAdds(formAside)" #formAside="ngForm">

<input type="text" [ngModel]="searchAside.order" name="order">
</form>

 ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.formModel.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
      order => {
        this.searchAside['order'] = order;
      }, error => {
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with two way data binding? [(ngModel)]="searchAside.order"?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Angular triggers a change detection on memory reference change, not on property change.

Try using the `ChangeDetectorRef` to manually trigger a detection, or create a new object memory reference with

```
this.searchAside = { ...this.searchAside, order };
```

Comment: this.searchAside = { ...this.searchAside, order }; didnt work. Is there another solution to avoid use ChangeDetector?